# Click and fade only works once

Tags: jquery

I want to work more than once.

Works but no fade:

```
$('#rate' + asinid + '').fadeOut(500);
$('#like' + asinid + '').html(html).fadeIn(500);
$('#rate' + asinid + '').click(function () {
  peticionseg(asinid);
});
```

Now it works but only once:

```
$('#rate' + asinid + '').fadeOut(500, function () {
  $('#like' + asinid + '').html(html).fadeIn(500);
});

$('#rate' + asinid + '').click(function () {
  peticionseg(asinid);
});
```

Comment: please provide a JSFiddle !

Comment: What elements are inside `'#like' + asinid` ?

Comment: Please format properly your code next time. It was unreadable the way it was. Second, "... Now it works but only once...," it is pretty clear it will only fade once but it is not clear the relation that clicking and fading should have